# Python: Adding to class variable in setUp not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

```
class TestHead(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.num = 0

    def setUp(self):
        self.num += 1

    def test1(self):
        print self.num

    def test2(self):
        print self.num
```

output:

```
1
1
```

I don't understand. The `setUp` should be ran after each test and all it does is increment `self.num` Shouldn't it be

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, a class variable is shadowed by an instance variable on creation- so self.num is an instance variable initialized by the class value. You could access TestHead.num to get a class singleton.